# NoReverseMatch at /tienda/

Tags: python, django, django-urls

tengo un pequeño problema con el envio de un parametro por url. Este es mi html donde se debe mostrar la información:

```
{% for i in productos %}
            <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 100%; margin: 5px 5px;">
                <img src="{{i.imagen.url}}" class="card-img-top">
                <div class="card-body" style="text-align: center;">
                    <h7 class="card.title">{{i.nombre}}</h7>
                    <p class="card.text">$&nbsp;{{i.precio}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-fotter text-center">
                    <a href="{% url 'carro:agregar' i.id %}" class="btn btn-success">Agregar al carrito</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Aqui creo las Url para enviar los datos al carrito de compra y el namespace para los url:

```
app_name="carro"
urlpatterns = [
path("agregar/<int:producto_id>/", views.agregar_producto, name="agregar"),
path("eliminar/<int:producto_id>/", views.eliminar_producto, name="eliminar"),
path("restar/<int:producto_id>/", views.restar_producto, name="restar"),
path("limpiar/", views.limpiar_carro, name="limpiar"),
]
```

Y dentro del URLS del proyecto agrego el path 'carro/'

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('servicios/', include('AppServicios.urls')),
path('blog/', include('AppBlog.urls')),
path('contacto/', include('AppContacto.urls')),
path('tienda/', include('AppTienda.urls')),
path('carro/', include('AppCarrito.urls')),
path('', include('ProyectoWebApp.urls')),
]
```

No se muy bien que puede ser, porque cuando borro esta linea ({% url 'carro:agregar' i.id %}) y elimino el path del urls del proyecto si me funciona y ya he revisado si estoy mandando los datos correctamente y no encuentro el fallo. Gracias <3

Comment: Dices que tienes un pequeño problema pero no detallas cual es

Comment: line 3, in <module>from tienda.models import Producto ModuleNotFoundError: 
No module named 'tienda' line 2, in <module>from .import views. En la web no me da ningun error, me dice que no puede acceder al sitio, esos errores me los en la terminal

Comment: eso no es error de la url, es un error de importación, lo que tienes que mostrar es la estructura de tus directorios